# Background Threading C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I am working on a software C# windows. I want to run there 6 web browser simultaneously. There are 6 different website navigate in each browser and I want to fill value in them simultaneously.
Using thread all browser are running and website navigating correctly. But my problem is that value is filling one by one in each browser. Please suggest me how I fill all value simultaneously in each site and also background threading(thread run in hidden mode)

```
frmBrowser  frmBz = new frmBrowser();

void bbyp_com()
{
    frmBrowser1 frmB = new frmBrowser1();
    try
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(bbyp_com));
            return;
        }
        frmB.MdiParent = frmBz;
        frmB.Show();
        frmBz.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);                

        if (!Navigate(ref frmB.webBrowser1,Global.Website[Global.WebsiteIndex(Global.ListingQueue[5])].urlListing))
            throw new System.ArgumentException("", "");

            frmB.Text = frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Url.ToString();                                  
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["FrontPage_Form2"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["COMPANY"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("BusinessTitle").InnerText);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["FrontPage_Form2"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["CTYPE"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("Category").SelectSingleNode("CategoryOption1").InnerText);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["FrontPage_Form2"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["ADDRESS"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("Street_Address").InnerText);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["FrontPage_Form2"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["CITY"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("City").InnerText);

            if (!Global.ComboSelect(frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["FrontPage_Form2"].GetElementsByTagName("select")["ST"], Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("State").InnerText, "Select a state"))
                throw new System.ArgumentException("", "");

            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["FrontPage_Form2"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["ZIP"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("Zipcode").InnerText);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["FrontPage_Form2"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["BTN"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("Phone").InnerText);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["FrontPage_Form2"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["WEB_SITE"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("Website").InnerText);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["FrontPage_Form2"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["EMAIL"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("ContactE-Mail").InnerText);
            TimeDelay(1000);

            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["FrontPage_Form2"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["B1"].InvokeMember("click");
            if (!IsDone(ref frmB.webBrowser1))
                throw new System.ArgumentException("", "");
            frmB.Text = frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Url.ToString();
            TimeDelay(50000);
            if (!Success(ref frmB.webBrowser1, "Thank You!"))
                throw new System.ArgumentException("", "");

            counter--;
            TimeDelay(1000);
            frmB.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            counter--;
            TimeDelay(1000);
            frmB.Close();
            lblFailed.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(lblFailed.Text) + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
```

**Second Function**

```
    void yellowusa_com()
    {
        frmBrowser1 frmB = new frmBrowser1();
        try
        {                
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(yellowusa_com));
                return;
            }
            frmB.MdiParent = frmBz;
            frmB.Show();
            frmBz.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);

            if (!Navigate(ref frmB.webBrowser1,Global.Website[Global.WebsiteIndex(Global.ListingQueue[4])].urlListing))
                throw new System.ArgumentException("", "");
            frmB.Text = frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Url.ToString();                           
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["lname"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("BusinessTitle").InnerText);
            TimeDelay(100);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["comments"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectNodes("Website")[4].SelectSingleNode("Category").InnerText);
            TimeDelay(200);            
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["lContact"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("ContactDetails").SelectSingleNode("Name").SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText + ' ' 
                                                                                                + Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("ContactDetails").SelectSingleNode("Name").SelectSingleNode("LastName").InnerText);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["lAddress"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("Street_Address").InnerText);

            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["lCity"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("City").InnerText);
            if (!Global.ComboSelect(frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("select")["lState"], Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("State").InnerText, "- Select"))
               throw new System.ArgumentException("", "");
            string phone = Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("Phone").InnerText.Substring(0, 3)
                         + Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("Phone").InnerText.Substring(4, 3)
                         + Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("Phone").InnerText.Substring(8, 4);

            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["lZip"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("Zipcode").InnerText);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["n1Phone"].SetAttribute("value", phone);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["lEmail"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("ContactE-Mail").InnerText);


            try
            {
                string fax = Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("FaxNumber").InnerText.Substring(0, 3)
                           + Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("FaxNumber").InnerText.Substring(4, 3)
                           + Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("FaxNumber").InnerText.Substring(8, 4);

                frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["lFax"].SetAttribute("value",fax);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }

            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["websiteURL"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("Website").InnerText);
            frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("textarea")["describeBiz"].SetAttribute("value", Global.XmlData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Author")[Global.AuthorDefault()].SelectSingleNode("ClientName").SelectSingleNode("ClientListing").SelectSingleNode("BusinessProfile").SelectSingleNode("BasicCompanyDetails").SelectSingleNode("BusinessDescription").InnerText);

            if (!ShowCaptcha(ref frmB.webBrowser1, "recaptcha"))
                throw new System.ArgumentException("", "");

           string captchaval = objfrmCaptchaSettings.HumanCaptcha();

           frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")["recaptcha_response_field"].SetAttribute("value", captchaval);
           frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Forms["form"].GetElementsByTagName("input")[17].InvokeMember("click");

           if (!IsDone(ref frmB.webBrowser1))
                throw new System.ArgumentException("", "");

           frmB.Text = frmB.webBrowser1.Document.Url.ToString(); 
           if (!Success(ref frmB.webBrowser1, "Thank You"))
                throw new System.ArgumentException("", "");
           counter--;
           TimeDelay(1000);
           frmB.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            counter--;
            TimeDelay(1000);
            frmB.Close();
            lblFailed.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(lblFailed.Text) + 1).ToString();
            Exception();
        }
    }
```

/* Here frmBz is MDi parent

Here i only put two function because of low space

**I am using this**

```
Thread m_thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(hotfrog_com));
m_thread1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

Thread m_thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(yahoolocal_com));
m_thread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

Thread m_thread3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ezlocal_com));
m_thread3.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

Thread m_thread4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(merchantcircle_com));
m_thread4.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

Thread m_thread5 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(yellowusa_com));
m_thread5.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

Thread m_thread6 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(bbyp_com));
m_thread6.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
```

**To start Thread**
**selectedwebsites is list**

```
while (selectedwebsites.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        if (selectedwebsites[j] == "hotfrog.com")
        {
            counter++;
            m_thread1.Start();
            selectedwebsites.RemoveAt(j);
            break;
        }

        if (selectedwebsites[j] == "local.yahoo.com")
        {
            counter++;
            m_thread2.Start();
            selectedwebsites.RemoveAt(j);
            break;
        }

        if (selectedwebsites[j] == "ezlocal.com")
        {
            counter++;
            m_thread3.Start();
            selectedwebsites.RemoveAt(j);
            break;
         }

         if (selectedwebsites[j] == "merchantcircle.com")
         {
             counter++;
             m_thread4.Start();
             selectedwebsites.RemoveAt(j);
             break;
         }

         if (selectedwebsites[j] == "yellowusa.com")
         {
             counter++;
             m_thread5.Start();
             selectedwebsites.RemoveAt(j);
             break;
         }

         if (selectedwebsites[j] == "bbyp.com")
         {
             counter++;
             m_thread6.Start();
             selectedwebsites.RemoveAt(j);
             break;
         }
     }
     catch(Exception) {}
 }
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are having problems with?

Comment: Are the web browsers hosted in a single form?

Comment: @Erno yes, I have taken a single form name(frmBrowser1) and there is a webBrowser. I also take another form(frmBrowser) which is MDI parent. i create instance of frmbrowser1 in each function(which are shown in code) and make it child of frmBrowser form. Please check the code.

Comment: The user interface of a form (ans its children) are normally rendered/executed on a single thread. Do you actually need all the web pages to be visible?

Comment: @Erno yes i need atleast 6 websites are visible and rest working in backgrond... Do you ever use Senuke or another article submitter i also want to do same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is the bare basics to run the `Method WebSiteOne` in its own thread.
I suggest you read up on threads, there are lots of good examples to get started.

```
Thread threadWebSiteOne = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WebSiteOne));
threadWebSiteOne.Start();
```

Update using BackGroundWorker.

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;  //Gets called when work completed

bw.RunWorkerAsync();

static void bw_DoWork (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    //Load Webpage X EG : hotfrog_com();
}
```

Comment: this one i am using to create 6 differ thraeds

Comment: Thread m_thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(hotfrog_com));
m_thread1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

Comment: i think after navigate i use Application.doEvent() so it might be complete one by one

Comment: yes all are working fine thanks. but the main problem is its navigate all 6 websites 6 web Browser in but its not filling details in all browser simultaneously. it one by one. I use Application.DOEvent may be this is the cause

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use a browser for this? Can't you use a HTTP request directly to the server? Browsers just serve a UI which is only needed if a 'human' is supposed to fill out the fields in my opinion.

In your case it would be best if the websites your submitting data to would expose the form you're filling out as a webservice of some kind (however this is best case scenario :)).

Comment: I have around 100 websites and i want to submit data in that using software. So i am using threads and want to use back ground threading

Comment: If you have this many websites (assuming you're maintaining them yourself) why don't you expose a webservice so you can make your requests to a service instead of calling on another process for making your requests. Having services will make your code much easier to read and maintain

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have added one background thread and then open the browser one by one in this thread?

Try `System.Threading.Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem()` and then put your call to the browser in this.

Comment: its navigate all 6 websites 6 web Browser in but its not filling details in all browser simultaneously. it one by one. I use Application.DOEvent may be this is the cause

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your threads do no useful work at all since they immediately marshal all of the pertinent stuff back onto the UI thread. I have shorted your code below to make it easier to see.

```
void bbyp_com()
{
    frmBrowser1 frmB = new frmBrowser1();
    try
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(bbyp_com));
            return;
        }
        // All of the useful work happens here.
    }
    catch
    {
      // Stuff omitted here for brevity.
    }
}
```

Notice how the worker thread immediately calls `Control.Invoke` to recursively reenter the method on the UI thread *before* any real work happens. And on top of that the worker thread actually waits for the UI thread to finish before the worker thread itself terminates. The effect is worse<sup>1</sup> than just doing everything on the UI thread from the very beginning since a new thread has been created to nothing more than waste resources.

The naive solution would be to omit the call to `Control.Invoke` in worker thread and let it do all of the work. But alas, this will not work either since most of the useful work requires doing stuff to UI elements which, as you probably know, is forbidden on anything other than a UI thread.

You are going to have to radically alter your strategy.

Comment: its navigate all 6 websites 6 web Browser in but its not filling details in all browser simultaneously. it one by one. I use Application.DOEvent may be this is the cause